# How to click on the first element which is suggested to us while searching

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need your help here.

As given below image, You will see the company search box in the image(Ex: **Accenture**). We are sending the company name through selenium. The name is being sent but when we are clicking on the first suggested name, It is not getting clicked.

I am working on the belw URL on linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101165590&keywords=Machine%20learning&location=United%20Kingdom

I want to send company name by applying filter.

[image]

I tried below thinks.

```
company_button = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//button[@aria-label="Company filter. Clicking this button displays all Company filter options."]')))
company_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
company_send = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="search-basic-typeahead search-vertical-typeahead"]//input')
company_send.send_keys("Office Depot")
auto_complete = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//li[@class='search-reusables__collection-values-item']")
auto_complete[0].click()
```

I need your help. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code for the above problem. It took me a while to find the dropdown list. So, to find it, I initially printed all the HTML in the IDE after searching keyword in the inputbox, then searched for the options keyword, such as "Accenture" and "Accenture India". This way i found the desired element to get access to the drop down items.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
action = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# Opening page and logging in
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin')
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('Your UserID')
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys('Your Password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign in"]').click()

# Search and Enter
time.sleep(5)
SearchTextBox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Search"]')))
action.move_to_element(SearchTextBox).click().send_keys('Machine Learning').perform()
SearchTextBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Click on Jobs
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Jobs"]'))).click()

# Clicking company filter
company_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Company filter. Clicking this button displays all Company filter options."]')))
company_button.click()

# Send Accenture keyword in the inputbox
# Please modify the xpath as per your understanding. Relative path
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Add a company"]'))).send_keys('Accenture')
time.sleep(5)

# Collect all the options
All_selection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//span[contains(@class,'search-typeahead-v2__hit-text t-14 t-black')]")

# Printing all the options
for i in All_selection:
    print(i.text)

# Click on the first Option.
All_selection[0].click()
```

Do let me know if you have any query. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Swaroop thanks for your response. Your code is working when we are not login in Linkedin then I request you.. Will you try once login in Linkdin please. Then you notice the element have changed a bit.. I request you again please try to check with login in Linkedin.

Comment: Hi @KunalJoshi, I have updated my code as per your requirement. now i am able to select the company name after login. Before running this script please provide username and password in the script. Do let me know if this script is working for you or not. Run multiple times and see the result. Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Hi @Swaroop It's working fine. Thank you so much your kindness. Only the last question can you tell us how to extract this xpath("//span[contains(@class,'search-typeahead-v2__hit-text t-14 t-black')]") for future reference

Comment: 1. I have written code till it type "Accenture" in the company textbox and suggestions show upthen.  2. After that i have executed `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').get_attribute('innerHTML')` code. which will print the bodies inner html. In that inner html you can find the find the options visible on UI. And after finding that element i have constructed my XPATH accordingly. Thats how i got that code.